# Анимация перелистывания, как в ibooks

Tags: анимация, iphone, transition

Мне нужно сделать приложение-книгу, для этого нужен эффект перелистывания страниц, в iphone SDK включён эффект перелистывания, как в блокноте, но мне нужно, чтобы "страница" занимала половину экрана.

Я нашёл много демо этого эффекта (half curved page transition), но ни одно не смог запустить на свежей версии SDK.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какую библиотеку вы используете для эффекта перелистывания страниц.

Answer (score 1):

Это стандартный эффект, который доступен в качестве одного из переходов для `UIPageViewController` (он стоит по умолчанию - **Page Curl**)